# Split multiple values within a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to get the values of col1 in 3 different columns with separate headers.

```
      Date/Time                      col1
0     2019/03/20 10:00:09     212.0/212.0/212.0
```

so far I tried,

```
import pandas as pd        
data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
s= pd.Series(data1['col1'])    
s.str.split(pat = '/', expand=True)

       0        1       2
0     212.0   212.0   212.0
```

now, how could I put headers and accumulate them into data1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `s` is the dataframe shown in your output, you can `merge` this dataframe into the original `data1` and rename the columns using `df.rename`:

```py
data1.merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename({0: 'colA', 1: 'colB', 2: 'colC'}, axis=1)

    Datetime            col1                colA    colB    colC
0   2019/03/20 10:00:09 212.0/212.0/212.0   212.0   212.0   212.0
1   2019/03/20 10:30:09 222.0/222.0/222.0   222.0   222.0   222.0
2   2019/03/20 11:00:09 232.0/232.0/232.0   232.0   232.0   232.0
```

or if you have your original dataframe `data1` you can do this in a single step:

```py
data1[['colA','colB','colC']] = data1.col1.str.split('/', expand=True)

    Datetime            col1                colA    colB    colC
0   2019/03/20 10:00:09 212.0/212.0/212.0   212.0   212.0   212.0
1   2019/03/20 10:30:09 222.0/222.0/222.0   222.0   222.0   222.0
2   2019/03/20 11:00:09 232.0/232.0/232.0   232.0   232.0   232.0
```

Comment: I took the second solution, with a small tweak its working fine.

p= data1['col_name']

data1[['col1','col2','col3']] =p.str.split('/', expand=True)